# Why it return error when I indicate a params with the type on initialize method?

Tags: php, phalcon

I indicate params with type on initialize method:

```php
class ContactForm extends Form
{
    public function initialize($entity = null, array $options = [])
    { 
    }
}
```

When try to create object of the ContactForm class, it gives me an error:

```
Argument 2 passed to ContactForm::initialize() must be of the type array, null given
```

If I will clean the type of $options param, it will work fine. So, my question is "On initialize we should not indicate params with type, are not we?"

Thanks.

Comment: How you are creating the `object`?

Comment: O sorry, I forgot write it. I created it like this:
```
$form = ContactForm();
```

Comment: by giving the `type` you are enforcing the value should be array but not allowed `null` to accept null kindly do this `public function initialize($entity = null, ?array $options = [])`